python await asyncio.sleep(3600) Как отменить asyncio.sleep
ЭТО ТЕЛЕГРАМ БОТ.
В данный момент это работает так:
Нажал на /start     бот удаляет /start и присылает сообщения текст.
через час.  бот удаляет присланное сообщение и присылает его повторно.
Если отправить еще раз /start , то бот будет присылать в час уже 2 сообщения.
еще раз на /start  3 сообщения будет в час присылать.
ЗАДАЧА.  При нажатии на /start второй раз -  Нужно отменять предыдущее  await asyncio.sleep(3600) и запускать await asyncio.sleep(3600) заново.
например:   нажал на /start  пошел отчет 3600 сек.   через 600сек нажал еще раз и отчет начинается заново 3600сек.
async def start(message, state):
    try: 
     await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    except:
       pass  
    if message.text=='/start':
      await start_command(message, state)
      await asyncio.sleep(3600)
      await start(message, state)


Запускаете ожидание и все что идет ниже в отдельном таске (asyncio.create_task), таск сохраняете в глобальную переменную. При повторном запуске, проверяете, что таск уже запущен, если да - отменяете его методом cancel, запускаете заново. Либо используйте планировщик, типа aioscheduler, логика будет примерно такая же, только sleep не нужен будет, в планировщике просто указываете время, когда нужно запустить.

Спасибо.
Я понимаю о чем Вы, но я совсем не разбираюсь как это написать в коде.
asyncio.create_task - этот вариант пробовал, но не хватает знаний.
Можно написать  в коде пожалуйста,  если не сложно.
aioscheduler  желательно этот метод
